# typescript: Is there a way of saying, "This field is optional, but if it exists, it MUST have a value?"

Tags: typescript, types

```
type Fields = {
  [P in "foo" | "bar"]?: number; // in the real code, this is [P in anArrayOfStrings]
};

const field: Fields = {
  "foo": 3
}

Object.keys(field).forEach((fieldName) => {
  if (fieldName === 'foo') {
    const val: number = field.foo; // Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    console.log(val);
  }
});
```

[You can play with this code here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwM5QLxQN4CgpQDaAClHAHZQBEAZgPZ1VQA%201ARgIYBOVAugPwAuKOQCuAWzYQuAblwBfObgDGdcqmBQaCFMPhI0mHPmr1GwgMwLcuAPJsAVhGXAAdAGsIIVAAptBgEpXei4AUQ5lAAsfPx1kADkOcQgAzAA%20YwI4GihYg0TkzAwsAHIzEtS8AgJVdU0ANw5EYTFJaSN-FGCGOWqoWtQ6RAhXRDoAcx9GxADeqHkFWaA)

This error can be fixed by changing the previous line to `if (fieldName === 'foo' && fieldName.foo) {` My question is, is there a way of defining this type to say, "This *field* is optional, but if it exists, it MUST have a value?" In otherwords, is there a way I can specify the type so I can use the original if statement?

Comment: AFAIK no, and I think this is because JavaScript doesn't really distinguish between foo being undefined and foo just not existing on the object--in the end `field.foo` will be undefined in both cases. You'll have to explicitly check with `field.hasOwnProperty('foo')`. I don't think TS's optional properties differentiates between the two situations (since `foo?: number` just translates to `foo: number | undefined`) and then the aforementioned problem kicks in.

Comment: `"foo" in field` is much shorter and more readable.

Comment: @Aplet123 where would i put that? I tried that in the if statement and it had the same error

Comment: if you change your code to: const field: Fields = {  "foo": 3}; Object.defineProperty(field, 'foo', {value: undefined}); Do you still think TS should tell it is number or undefined?